# How can I get one single object from a Query using Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to get a User as JSONObject from a JSONArray. He has email as a unique value in database.

If I make a call like this:

```
@GET("users")
Call<List<User>> getUser(@Query("email") String email);
```

I have to receive the data that way:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<User>> call,
                           @NonNull Response<List<User>> response) {
        List<User> users_list = response.body();

        if (users_list != null) {
               User user = users_list.get(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<User>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Because my call returns a list of only one element. Is there any other way to get the object directly, not being in a list?

The response I get is like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 17,
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        ...
    }
]
```

And I want to get just:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    ...
}
```

If I replace

```
List<User> with User
```

in GET method and in the call it won't work. I'm looking for some method like FirstOrDefault() from .NET Core 2 in C# or something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the response

Comment: Retrofit offers a concept of interceptors, but the better solution would be to fix your API to not return a List

Comment: Another option is combine with Rxjava, and use the `.first()` operator, but adding such a library just for this feature seems too much